# Hotkey for debugging a test case in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

In a normal java project with e.g. JUnit 4 test classes:

I want to debug either the whole test class currently open in the editor, or one specific test case.

I know Ctrl+Shift+F10 will run the relevant test when the cursor is on the class declaration or test method declaration, and I know I can click on the little
green arrow to debug or run code coverage.

My question is - is there a hotkey? Is it possible to set one? All this mouse business tends to really ruin my flow.

Thanks!

Comment: "is there a hotkey" => yes command-shift-r (for run),  command-shift-d (for debug) on OSX. Check https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: Isn't that "Replace in path" according to the link you just gave? In any case, I was referring to Windows, but thanks anyway.

Comment: yeah you are right it's CTRL not command in fact, you still got the nice pdf :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer my own question - yes!
The relevant keymap is called **Debug context configuration**, screenshot attached below in which I bound it to Ctrl+Shift+F11
[image: IntelliJ bind debug context]

Comment: This even works if you have a default JUnit config with some custom build parameters (like for maven). You can use the hotkey and intellij will go grab your default JUnit config and use that on the clsas rather than simply doing a standard debug. Very cool!